# Karma (Jasmine/Angular) TestRunner: get rid of href="#" on Spec List

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm testing an Angular 7 CLI project with Karma/Jasmine. Basically it works well, but there's a weird problem:

As soon as at least one test fails, Karma selects "Failures" instead of "Spec List" (which of course is fine).

Now the problem: when I want to view the overview of all tests ("Spec List") instead, this is not possible, because the "Spec List" element has set href="#" (and by this reloads the page).

As a workaround I of course can remove the href with developer tools, but I'd like to know if there's a more reasonable fix for this?[image]